# why "\n" disappear when I try do print out element of a array?

Tags: ruby

Below is my code

```
lines = File.readlines("test.txt")
print lines
print "\n#{lines[0]}"
```

The result shows

```
["x = 2\n", "print \"2+2=\#{x+x}\"\n"]
x = 2
```

Why "\n" disappear when I try to print lines[0]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` disappears because `print` prints it out as a linebreak, this is why your result reads:

```
["x = 2\n", "print \"2+2=\#{x+x}\"\n"]
x = 2
```

And not:

```
["x = 2\n", "print \"2+2=\#{x+x}\"\n"]x = 2
```

If you want the linebreaks to be preserved as `\n` in your output, use `inspect`

```
lines = File.readlines("test.txt")
print lines.inspect
print "\n#{lines[0]}".inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the escape sequence for the newline character, so that's what gets printed. Try `\\n` if you want to print the actual string `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

\n is an escape sequence for strings which denotes a new line. Your string is store as `"x = 2\n"` in the program but the your output program would parse that string and display accordingly. \n snit really disappearing, your REPL has output a new line too.

Edit: If you want Ruby to ignore parsin \n in your string just use single quotes instead of double quotes. Example: print 'x = 2\n' will print it as it is.

Comment: I see. Waht if I want to show all of them when I print lines[0]? like "x =2\n"

Answer (score 0):

in your lines variable you have set 
**File.readlines("test.txt")**. 
Its work is to split all text by **\n** character. lines is now an array of text that is splitted by \n character. Thats why **\n** character disappear  when you try to print it.